# Inject or Initialize Vue components in generated HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, trumbowyg

I use a an [WYSIWYG article editor](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/) that generates some HTML for articles that I save in the database and later show to the user.

The problem is I need to insert Vue components into this auto generated HTML for showing dynamic products. I can make a custom block in the editor that adds in HTML but I want it to work as a Vue component that updates the product description directly from the database.

What Im thinking now is to add a button that adds a div with a data property of the products ID. I can then replace that div in the code with a Vue component with the same ID by injecting a component.

Another idea I had was to simply add in components like `<product id="1031"/>` as plain html and then try to compile the whole article HTML with Vue but I read that the `v-html` directive only compile code as plain HTML.

Is this possible? Or is there any better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the full build of Vue (not the runtime only build) you can initialize a new instance of Vue and mount it wherever you like, pass in data etc.

```js
// Main app        
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    stuff: 'inserted message'
  },
  methods: {
    clicked() {
      // Add new
      new Vue({
        template: `<h1 style="color: red;">{{ message }}</h1>`,
        parent: this,
        data: {
          message: 'new message'
        }
      }).$mount(document.getElementById('more'))
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  There are some things here before like {{ stuff }}
  but when you press <button @click="clicked()">add more</button>
  you can add more things here:
  <div id="more"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not using the full build unfortunately but this solution would work if I did, so I will mark it as correct. I actually solved this with a new parent component with a custom render function.

Comment: Can you call the render function without the full build? Would you mind showing me how you did it? I'm curious @nilsi